# Angular-cli and Karma with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, karma-jasmine

I have searched the web and could not find a solution for my current problem, even though seems to be a **very common issue**...

When running `ng test` I find that the Karma browser opens and shows nothing:

[image]

Also, this is my console:

[image]

In order to use jQuery, I have done the things explained [here](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to).

**This is my `lib.ts` *(basically the same as `vendor.ts`)*:**

```
// jQuery
declare let jQuery: any;

// RxJS
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';


// Dependencies
window['jQuery'] = require('jquery');
window['$'] = window['jQuery'];
import 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery!jquery-color/jquery.color.js';
import 'jquery-ui-npm/jquery-ui.min.js';

require('bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'); // required for X-editable
require('bootstrap/js/popover.js'); // required for X-editable
require('bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'); // required for bootstrap-colorpicker
require('bootstrap/js/tab.js'); //
require('bootstrap/js/modal.js'); //

window['moment'] = require('moment');

import 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery!jquery-color/jquery.color.js'
```

I import `lib.ts` to `main.ts`.

And finally, the problematic component:

**aside-chat-boxes.ts:**

```
'use strict';

declare let $: any;

$.widget("ui.chatbox", {
   // A bunch of stuff here
}
```

I didn't put all the code of this component for the sake of who's reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding this to the top part of my component:

```
import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';
```

It's not the solution that I was looking for, but is a useful workaround.

I'm still amazed of all the problems that we have when using jQuery in an Angular project...

**Update (04-01-2018)**

The best approach should be to add jQuery to `karma.conf.js` in the `files: []` array. Such as:

```
files: [
  // imports of dependencies
  ...

  // importing jQuery
  'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
]
```

Comment: where di you put that exactly?

Comment: @dragonmnl I don't really remember. I believe I put this in the top part of my component. But now you should be able to add jQuery to the `karma.conf.js` file

Comment: @dragonmnl I have updated my answer. Hope it helps you!

Comment: thanks @SrAxi. in the end I did fundamentally the same thing

Comment: @dragonmnl Nice! ;)